# How to select a radio button by default in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a radio button and I would like to default the first item as checked by default. How do I go about doing that? Below is my source code for the radio button.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radRiskLevel" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem Value="High">High</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="Mid">Mid</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="Low">Low</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **ASPX Markup**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radRiskLevel" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem Value="High" Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="High">High</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="Mid">Mid</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="Low">Low</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 7):

> Selecting default value via ASPX markup:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radRiskLevel" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem Value="High" Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="Mid">Mid</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="Low">Low</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

> Selecting default value via C# codebehind:

```
if (!IsPostBack) // prevent from selecting default value during postback
{
    if (radRiskLevel.SelectedIndex == -1) //-1 is the indication of none selected
    {   
        radRiskLevel.SelectedIndex = 0; // the index of items in radiobutton in the list you want to select
        //radRiskLevel.Items.FindByText("Select").Selected = true;  //can also be selected by text, need to pass text name as parameter 
        //radRiskLevel.Items.FindByValue("High").Selected = true;  //can also be selected by value, need to pass value name as parameter
    }
}
```